# Mongoose update query does not work on nested object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a model with nested object and I want to update single field of that document but unable to do it. I could not understand why it's not working.

This is my `model`

```
var sampleItemSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    },
    location: Object,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    sample: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sample'}
});
```

And this is my one of document.

```
{ createdAt: Thu Apr 21 2016 19:46:17 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  __v: 0,
   sample: 571911df9a97810c3f35d83d,
  location: { city: 'Kildare' },
 content: 
  { images: [],
  price: { currency: 'EUR', amount: 2000 },
  createdAt: '2016-04-21T17:46:17.349Z',
  category: { id: '2012', name: 'Animals | Ponies' },
  body: 'Beaulieu Ginger Pop (Ben) is a 14 year old 13.2hh grey roan  New Forest pony. He has a full green passport, is microchipped and is   fully up...',
 title: '13.2hh All rounder Gelding' },
id: '12123191',
_id: 571911e99a97810c3f35d845 }
```

Here what I tried yet.

I am just giving part of code

```
 models.SampleItem.find({
  sample: sample
}, function(err, sampeItemList) {
  console.log('Total sample: ', sampeItemList.length);
  async.eachSeries(sampeItemList, function(item, next) {
            item.content.body = "want to update this field";
            item.save(function(err, updatedItem) {
              console.log('Updated description...', index);
  })
})
})
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like `item.content.body` isn't defined in the schema you provided, Try defining the subobjects under `content` in the schema.

Comment: I have given content type "object". Is it wrong to store object? if it's wrong then why data are storing?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose does not allow you to use `Object` as a schema type. Instead set the `type` to `Schema.Types.Mixed`. This will give you an object with whatever properties you want to set.

You can see the list of all the valid schema types [in the Mongoose Schema Types documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

(You probably want to change the `location` field to `Schema.Types.Mixed` as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose doesn't allow 'Object' as a type. Use 'Schema.Types.Mixed' for properties which have flexible/unknown values.